# Why should I specify a data context class when scaffolding a view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When adding a new view to an ASP.NET MVC 5 project using the Add View dialog pictured below, I'm invited to choose a template and a model class, which allows me to quickly generate a form for creating new instances of the model or a view that displays the model's properties. But why should the view care what the data context class is? In my project, whether or not I specify the data context class, the same view is generated, but I'm guessing there's a scenario where it would make a difference. What might that be?

[image: ASP.NET MVC]

Comment: Maybe idea is while you are scaffolding a view and you choose Create Template, Model Class and Data Context Class, server side code for saving item in database should be generated inside Action but nothing happen in Action.

Comment: Not a duplicate. When adding a controller with read/write actions it makes sense since the data context is used to do the reading and writing in each method. For a view it's not clear why it's needed but has the effect mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you refer to an existing DbContext then the wizard will insert `public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }` (if it doesn't already exist) in your DbContext derived class . Looks like Visual Studio doing some of the leg work.

Comment: Yup, I see that now. Except it added it with the full namespace for all types.

`public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication.Models.Employee> Employees { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes I simplified the above a little.