# What is the difference when you add View with DataContextClass and without it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am adding all my views without **DataContextClass** and I wonder if I am going to face issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[**From here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343191/why-should-i-specify-a-data-context-class-when-scaffolding-a-view) =>

If you refer to an existing DbContext then the wizard will insert

`public DbSet<YourDbSet> YourDbSet { get; set; }`

if it doesn't already exist in your DbContext derived class . Looks like Visual Visual Studio doing some of the leg work.

And the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @steve, has my above answer helped you in anyway?